# Anyone having an App Engine running in EU without Premium Account?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have been using Google Compute Engine for quite some time for a project. I have found out that my project is better suited for their App Engine.

Therefore i tried to create an App Engine instance but i couldn't figure out how to create on in EU Datacenters. Later i found out that you either has to be a premium user or has to fill out this request form: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/viewform?formkey=dDllb3FHLS1IdXVIcjVKR3FScklka1E6MQ

Have any of you been able to get an App Engine running in EU Datacenters without being Premium User?

-Jesper

Comment: Anyone? - it is now more than 3 weeks since i signed up for the EU data centers and i haven't heard anything from google

Comment: well they prioritize premium (paying) customers over those who filled the forms.... maybe that's what's happening, even if it DOES seem like a long time.  still no answer from them?

Comment: No. unfortunately i still haven't received an answer from them.. I'm waiting for them to accept me so i can launch a new application i have been working on. It is ready to launch, but i don't wanna launch it in the US data centers since all of my costumers is located within europe.

Comment: Do you have specific EU regulations associated with your project?Because from what I can tell, if it's not EU regulated, you don't REALLY need that account.  Of course if you want less latency, being assured you have EU servers will provide that.  But to be honest, the App Engine already works to minimize latency, so you will most likely end up on EU servers.  Having that special account just validates your data will NEVER leave EU soil

Answer (score 1):

All documentation backs your statement of requiring billing for App Engine EU access.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/uploading
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/premier/

Someone in sales or support may help.
https://cloud.google.com/contact/
https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/3420056?hl=en&ref_topic=3473162

Out of curiosity, would you mind sharing where you found the form you linked?

Comment: The form is linked from this page: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/uploading ("fill out this form"). The response rate seems to be rather low...